# How do I prevent Highstock right range handle keep slipping off the max value when adding data

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highstock chart with three lines. When I add data, it will at in semi regular cases let the max range handle move off the right side, and then stay put instead of staying glued to the right side as expected. This behavior is not wanted.

Before it slips:
[image]
After it slips:
[image]

I have made a simplified example 
https://jsfiddle.net/eskil_saatvedt/rdwdbht1/3/

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {

  Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
      useUTC: false
    }
  });

  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
    },

    rangeSelector: {
      buttons: [{
        count: 1,
        type: 'minute',
        text: '1M'
      }, {
        count: 5,
        type: 'minute',
        text: '5M'
      }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All'
      }],
      inputEnabled: false,
      selected: 2
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Live random data'
    },

    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
      name: 'Random data',
      data: (function() {
        // generate an array of random data
        var data = [],
          time = (new Date()).getTime();
        data.push([
          time +1 * 1000,
          Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
        ]);

        return data;
      }())
    },
    {
      name: 'Random data2',
      data: (function() {
        // generate an array of random data
        var data = [],
          time = (new Date()).getTime();
        data.push([
          time +1 * 1000,
          Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
        ]);

        return data;
      }())
    },
    {
      name: 'Random data3',
      data: (function() {
        // generate an array of random data
        var data = [],
          time = (new Date()).getTime();
        data.push([
          time +1 * 1000,
          Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
        ]);

        return data;
      }())
    }
    ]
  });

});

function UpdateData() {
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
  var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
    k = Math.round(Math.random() * 100)+50,
    z = Math.round(Math.random() * 100)+20;
  chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], false, false);
  chart.series[1].addPoint([x, z], false, false);
  chart.series[2].addPoint([x, k], false, false);
  chart.redraw();
}

setInterval(function() {
  UpdateData();
}, 1000);
```

Normally I would display 2 temperatures and gain, using it for room heat control.

Comment: I observed this, too, and noticed that when I manually re-adjusted the handle back to the edge, it stayed for a bit, and then slipped again. This could be a bug; you may wish to post this to the Highstock forum: http://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call setExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes) function after adding point with new range.

```
function UpdateData() {
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
  min = chart.xAxis[0].dataMin,
  max = chart.xAxis[0].dataMax,
  x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
    k = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 50,
    z = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 20;
  chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], false, false);
  chart.series[1].addPoint([x, z], false, false);
  chart.series[2].addPoint([x, k], false, false);

  chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min,x);
}
```

Example:
- https://jsfiddle.net/xh1sjk3L/

Comment: Thank you. 
It do not solve the case as this will force it to stay at start/end, but it did give me the pointer and I will to look at setExtremes.

Comment: use userMin instead of dataMin and the left side will stay where you put it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sebastian.

By using  max = chart.xAxis[0].userMax I was able to set the max value to max if it is close to the side. In the example 1 second

```
function UpdateData() {
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

  var userMax = chart.xAxis[0].userMax; // <- change

  var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
    k = Math.round(Math.random() * 100)+50,
    z = Math.round(Math.random() * 100)+20;
  chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], false, false);
  chart.series[1].addPoint([x, z], false, false);
  chart.series[2].addPoint([x, k], false, false);  
  chart.redraw(); // Redraw it again, as the left handle position I want is most often correct after the redraw.

// ----- change --------
  var deltaX = x - userMax;
  if (deltaX < 1000){ // the handle was closer to the end than 1 second
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(chart.xAxis[0].min,x);
  } 
}
```